# How to Self checksuming work?

Tags: c++, assembly

My Question how to self checksuming work and detect own checksum in memory of file and check if executable modified terminate app? like commercial exe protector vmprotect pelock themida etc.. and how algorithm using and how to embed checksum in own file of executable and detect if modified? how to work? for example check md5 or crc32 self checksum of binary executable sorry my bad english ;) Thank you!

Comment: This is either too broad or unclear, I can't really tell - so I voted unclear.

Comment: how to detect executable file own checksum sorry for my bad english ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with trying to put the checksum or hash directly into your executable. Such an approach would mean that the checksum/hash is going to be taken into account when determining the checksum/hash of your executable/binary. You can't encode the checksum/hash without affecting the resulting hash/checksum of the binary/executable.

Without knowing more details of your situation, you probably want to have the hash of the binary stored outside of the thing you are trying to compute the checksum/hash of (ex. externally on a server or in a file located relative to the executable, etc.). You compute this hash after you've built your program. Your program on launch could then locate itself on disk and compute the hash of itself and compare to the hash stored externally.

*Sorry if this would be better as a comment, but I don't have the rep to comment.*

Comment: You could embed the hash if the check function knows to exclude the bytes where the hash itself is stored, or to zero those bytes after loading the correct hash into register(s).  And yes you'd compute the hash of the whole file after building, but if you know where in the binary the hash is stored, you can modify those bytes in the executable.  (In the data section, or read-only-data.)

Comment: An anti-tampering check would have to be much more sophisticated than this, though, or else an attacker could pretty easily recompute the right hash and embed it.  Having it in a separate file would make it super-easy (unless it's buried deep in some other large data file with a custom binary format.)

Comment: @petercordes sign it with a private key, and check it (at run time) with the corresponding public key